# Fetching select attributes from Google Contact API

Tags: google-contacts-api

While working with https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference, I haven't figured out a way yet to ONLY have Google return gd$email & gd$name instead of the following it returns by default.

["id", "gd$etag", "updated", "app$edited", "category", "title", "link", "gd$email", "gd$name"]

For our business use case, we only need these two attributes, having all the above in the response increases the response Pay Load and thus response time.

Any leads ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the response you get with contacts API. I tried for retrieving all the contacts, but to include only email and phone number in the response.

Here is the request https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/guntupalliswathi@gmail.com/full ?fields=entry/gd:email,entry/gd:phoneNumber(I tried in oauth playground)

Response:

```
<entry>
 <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" address="xxxx@domain.com" primary="true"/>
</entry>
<entry>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile"   uri="tel:+91-0000-000-000"> </gd:phoneNumber>
 </entry>
 <entry>
 <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"  address="yyyy@domain.com" primary="true"/>
 </entry>
 <entry>
   <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile">(000) 000-0001</gd:phoneNumber>
 </entry>
```

Let me know if your issue is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
It works with XML as output format but strangely it doesn't work (google gives 400 Bad Request) with JSON as the output format.
Any leads here ?

Answer (score 0):

For JSON response, you can supply field list as follows:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?alt=json&fields=feed(entry(gd$name(gd$fullName))),feed(entry(gd$email(address)))

This will give you just full name and email per contact. Hope this works.